# Generate a call to a package function programatically given vector of package names

Tags: r

In my work I develop R packages that export R data objects (.RData). The name of these .RData files is always the same (e.g. files.RData). These packages also define and export a function that uploads the data to my database, say upload_data(). Inside upload_data() I first load the data using data(files, package = "PACKAGE NAME") and then push it into my database.

Let's say I have two packages, package1 and package2, which live on my file system. Given a vector of the package names (c("package1", "package2")), how would I go about to call 'upload_data()' programatically? Specifically, inside a script, how would I construct a call using "::" notation that constructs and evaluates a call like this: package1::upload_data()). I tried 'call' but couldn't get it right.

Comment: Kindly provide code examples

Comment: Do you really *need* to use `::` notation? You can directly get the function using `get("upload_data", envir = asNamespace("package1"))`

Comment: @Dason, that works! Completely forgot about get(). Simply calling this function with the parameters does the job (get("upload_data", envir = asNamespace("package1"))(host = "mongodb://localhost"). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* go the route of constructing the call using `::` notation and evaluating that - but it's probably just easier to directly use `get` and specify the package you want to grab from.

```
get("upload_data", envir = asNamespace("package1"))
```

will return the function the same as using `package1::upload_data` would but is much easier to deal with programatically.